# How to split a ViewModel into two lists on a view in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

So I have this view model for my products and their related options,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace CuttingEdgeOrderingSystem.Models
{
    public class ProductOptionVM
    {
        public string ProductName { get;  set; }
        public string ImageScr { get;  set; }
        public string Desc { get;  set; }
        public List<OptionsVM> Options { get;  set; }
        public int ProductId { get;  set;}
    }

    public class OptionsVM
    {
        public string OptionName { get;  set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }
        public int OptionsId { get;  set; }
    }
}
```

And I want to display the products individually with a list of their options underneath them with each option having a radio button.

This is my current view code. I have the products being produced as a list and cannot figure out how to get each option displayed in a list within this structure. Any help is appreciated.

```
@model IEnumerable<CuttingEdgeOrderingSystem.Models.ProductOptionVM>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Shop";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Products</h2>

<div class="row">
    @foreach (var product in Model)
    {
        <!-- Panel to display products-->
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 panel-height">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <span class="panel-title">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => product.ProductName)</span>
                <div class="">
                    <img src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => product.ImageScr)" class="panel-image" />
                </div>
                <div class="panel-default text-black panel-border">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => product.Desc)
                </div>
                <div class="panel-default text-black">
                    <!-- options for products go here -->

                </div>
                <div class="panel-default text-black">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Add to Cart</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call DisplayFor on each option like this:

```
<div class="panel-default text-black">
@for(var i = 0; i < product.Options.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(o => product.Options[i])
}
</div>
```

Not sure how nice DisplayFor will look in your case, but I think you get the idea here.

Comment: This helps a lot thanks! Now just need to figure out how to use radio buttons for each. Thank you for your help!